# Is there a way to use a standard action power when its not your turn?

Tags: dnd-4e

Is there any item, power, or feat that would allow you to use the Riposte Strike rogue power on someone else's turn other than using a readied action?  I'm trying to see if theres a way to trigger Riposte Strike twice in a turn and the only way I could think of is to somehow use Riposte Strike before you went on the first round of combat.

Comment: You said in comments on another answer that this needs to be whilst you haven't gone yet. Your current question leaves you open to answers that involve something that isn't a readied action, but rely on you having had your turn first. You might want to update it to explain the situation.

Comment: Isn't the 2nd attack of Riposte Strike an immediate? You only get one of those a round, what's the benefit of Riposte Striking more than once in a turn if you can only make the 2nd attack once?

Comment: @ObliviousSage Mr Tumnus appears to be interested in being able to do it in the first round of combat, before having had their first turn to set the attack up, if their comments on another answer hold.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I'm not sure that's the XY problem (the buck can stop easily at "I want to use Riposte Strike twice" and not be XY) but asking about using it on someone else's turn to use it twice _is_ an XY when there's other options available to perform it twice on your own turn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not so much.

There are a few classes (warlord, bard, shaman etc), that allow others to make attacks on their turn, but usually that *only* provides basic attacks. So unless you have one of those classes in your party, and have a way to turn Riposte Strike into a basic attack, you're out of luck (spoiler: there isn't a feat that does this which means you're probably out of luck).

So the answer here is pretty much "No"

Answer (score 3):

I know of one method of doing so - the Anticipate Action ability of the Talaric Strategist Paragon Path. Not sure how well this path may suit a Rogue.

> Anticipatory Action (11th level): When an enemy enters a square adjacent to you, you can spend an action point to take a standard action as an immediate interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to *Ready an Action.*

Comment: Thanks for the fast response but I'm looking for a method that would allow you to do so when its not your turn and you haven't gone yet.

Comment: Do you mean before you have had your first turn? Because you can't take Immediate actions before your first turn has come up by default, so that would make it even harder.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm trying to see if theres a way to trigger Riposte Strike twice in a turn and the only way I could think of is to somehow use Riposte Strike before you went on the first round of combat. Also, where is that rule listed? I've read through immediate actions in the rules compendium and didn't come across that passage.

Comment: @MrTumnus It'd be really great if you edit the information from that comment into your question.

Comment: Hm, it's a little ambiguous whether or not you can take Immediate Actions before your first turn. The only trigger reason is "haven't used one since the end of your last turn", but no comment on what happens when you haven't HAD a last turn yet. (It is clear though that the Surprised condition prevents you from taking immediate actions)